# Efficiently filter windowed observations in a pandas dataframe if they contain a certain value

Tags: python, string, pandas, filter, window

I have a pandas dataframe that has windows/chains of string observations indexed at the point of their first observation. The window is of a variable size. For this example we can say they're chains of 4 observations. I want to know how to most efficiently eliminate certain values if they have a specific observation anywhere in their windows, knowing that if the nth window begins with the value I am looking for, I know I can get rid of it, and the three windows before it because they will also contain the same value later in their windows. It is possible for a window to contain multiple instances of the value I want to filter for. Here's some sample data. Starting with a simple series of events, ser:

```
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'])
>>> ser
0     a
1     b
2     c
3     d
4     e
5     f
6     g
7     h
8     i
9     j
10    k
```

Then I turn this into a dataframe where each row is a window of n observations. Here n == 4.

```
df = pd.concat([ser.shift(-x) for x in range(4)], axis=1)
>>> df
    0    1    2    3
0   a    b    c    d
1   b    c    d    e
2   c    d    e    f
3   d    e    f    g
4   e    f    g    h
5   f    g    h    i
6   g    h    i    j
7   h    i    j    k
8   i    j    k  NaN
9   j    k  NaN  NaN
10  k  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Now I want to get rid of all the rows that include the value 'f' anywhere, i.e.:

desired_output

```
    0    1    2    3
0   a    b    c    d
1   b    c    d    e
6   g    h    i    j
7   h    i    j    k
8   i    j    k  NaN
9   j    k  NaN  NaN
10  k  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I'd like to avoid searching the whole dataframe as it only contains repetition of the first column, and my value for n can be somewhat long. In this example, what would be the best way to drop the columns that start with 'c', 'd', 'e', and 'f', knowing that they will all include an 'f' somewhere. Later I join all the strings in each row into one value but it seems like it should be easier to manipulate the data at this stage where everything is in different columns. This is with pandas 0.16.0 and must work on python 2.76 and python 3.4. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more efficient to search just the original series before concatenating, replace the values with nans, then drop those nans which is an inexpensive operation in pandas.

```
ser = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'])
ser.replace('f', float('nan'), inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([ser.shift(-x) for x in range(4)], axis=1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Compared to Colonel Beauvel's solution this has the advantage of being able to accept an iterable of strings as the first argument and filter for multiple strings at the same time. Another difference is that it eliminates all NA values which could be problematic but in my case was desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do, without searching the whole dataframe:

```
import numpy as np

ind = -np.arange(0, df.shape[1])+pd.Index(ser).get_loc('f')
df.iloc[np.setdiff1d(ser.index, ind)]

#Out[48]: 
#    0    1    2    3
#0   a    b    c    d
#1   b    c    d    e
#6   g    h    i    j
#7   h    i    j    k
#8   i    j    k  NaN
#9   j    k  NaN  NaN
#10  k  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, but isn't this still searching the whole dataframe?

Comment: This solution raises a "positional indexers are out-of-bounds" error. Your original answer (before the edit) works, though it searches through the whole dataframe.

Comment: You were right, this version does work but I prefer the solution before the edit because this one throws an error if the string you're trying to filter out is not in the dataframe.

Comment: adding a check before is a basic operation ... like if `'f' in set(df.values.flatten()):`